# Cross Apply Equivalent in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql, amazon-emr

I want to create the effect of a cross apply in AWS EMR Hive. I've got a little sample code here that runs in SQL Server 2017.

```
with r as (
select 1 as d
union all
select 2 as d
)
select * from r
cross apply (select 'f' as u) e;
```

How can I run the equivalent of this in EMR Hive?

I've checked out the [Lateral View](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) documentation, but it all references explode, and I don't have an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around with by just adding an extra field with a single value and joining the two tables together on that to produce the same effect.

It ended up looking something like:

```
with d as (
select column, 'AreYouKiddingMe' as k from table
), e as (
select column2, 'AreYouKiddingMe' as k from table2
)
select * from d inner join e on d.k = e.k
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of do `CROSS APPLY` you may do `CROSS JOIN` in your case. F.e.:

```sql
SET hive.strict.checks.cartesian.product = false;

WITH r AS (
    SELECT 1 AS d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS d
)
SELECT *
FROM r
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'f' AS u) e;
```